# TableCellRenderer lost

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

I've got an ArrayList bound to a JTable. After

```
 bindingGroup.unbind(); 
 bindingGroup.bind();
```

(done to refreshing data) I lost table cell renderer behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @camickr - agreed, it's quite obvious what the question is (once you know the typical problem) voted to re-open

Comment: who deleted (my and others') comments and why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the bind() methods do, but if they refresh the table by changing the model then the TableColumnModel is being recreated which causes you to lose any custom renderer you added to the table.

One solution is to add the renderer back to the table after you invoke the bind() methods.

Or after you create the JTable you can use:

```
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
```

to prevent the TableColumnModel from being recreated.

Comment: many thanks camickr and kleopatra for re-opening my question, next time I'll try to be more clear.

Comment: It Works. After binding I re-do setCellRenderer as You suggest. Thanks a lot camckir. I didn't know that bind cause loosing custom renderer. Thx.